# GUI Program crashes when trying to recall from a text file

Tags: c#

I'm not sure what the problem is here. My program can read the "text" and put it in the Title without any problems, but it crashes and doesn't change the size or color before it does so. I tried asking my classmates for help regarding this, but they say all my code looks correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace RetrieveCustomizedForm
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const char DELIM = ',';
    string recordIn;
    string[] fields;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        const string FILENAME = "C:\\Exercise5\\Data.txt";
        stuff stuff1 = new stuff();
        FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
        recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.Close();
        inFile.Close();



        while (recordIn != null)
        {
            fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
            stuff1.color = fields[0];
            stuff1.size = fields[1];
            stuff1.text = fields[2];

            if (fields[0] == "red")
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            if (fields[0] == "blue")
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
            if (fields[0] == "yellow")
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }
            if (fields[1] == "large")
            {
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
            }
            if (fields[1] == "small")
            {
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            }
            this.Text = fields[2];

        }


    }

    class stuff
    {
        public string color { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the value of fields[0], [1], and [2]?

Comment: Please provide the content of the Data.txt file

Answer (score 0):

fields : might be empty, end of the file?
Any file open error? trying to open it again while it is already opened in background?

Answer (score 0):

Some more information might be helpful. Like The others have said, what are the values of fields[0]-[2]? What errors are you receiving? It looks to me like one error you will receive is that your index is outside the bounds of the fields array...Give us some more info and we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
using (FileStream infile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(infile))
    {
        string recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
        while (recordIn != null)
        {
            fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
            stuff1.color = fields[0];
            stuff1.size = fields[1];
            stuff1.text = fields[2];

            if (fields[0] == "red")
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            if (fields[0] == "blue")
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
            if (fields[0] == "yellow")
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }
            if (fields[1] == "large")
            {
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
            }
            if (fields[1] == "small")
            {
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            }
            this.Text = fields[2];

        }
    }

}
```